# Cant understand the Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am just a newbie in C# and I read about the `INotifyPropertyChanged Event Handler` on MSDN Blog and searched here on "stackoverflow". But I don't really understand how to implement it in my code and how I have to bind the events and properties together.

I have already made a `BindingClass` with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the code is:

```
namespace Testing.Pages
{
  class BindingClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private string _setting;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public BindingClass()
    {

    }

    public BindingClass(string value)
    {
        _setting = value;
    }

    public string SettingProperty
    {
        get { return _setting; }
        set
        {
            _setting = value;
            // calling OnPropertyChanged whenever the property gets updated

        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string _setting = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_setting));
    }
  }
}
```

`SettingsPage.xaml`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PopupText"
               Grid.Row="0" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="0,0,0,20"
               Text="Your theme will be updated next time you start the app."
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="popup_animate">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="PopupText"
                                 AutoReverse="True"
                                 From="0.0"
                                 To="1.0"
                                 BeginTime="{x:Bind }"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                        ></DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </TextBlock.Resources>
    </TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="Change Theme?" 
                   Margin="10,10,0,0"></TextBlock>
        <RadioButton x:Name="DarkTheme_btn" 
                     Click="ChangeTheme_btn_Click" 
                     Content="Dark Theme" 
                     Margin="10,0,0,0"
                     GroupName="theme"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton x:Name="LightTheme_btn" 
                     Click="ChangeTheme_btn_Click" 
                     Content="Light Theme" 
                     Margin="10,0,0,0"
                     GroupName="theme"></RadioButton>
```

and the code-behind file `SettingsPage.xaml.cs` is:

```
namespace Testing.Pages
{

/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
  public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
  {
    BindingClass notifyProperty = new BindingClass();

    public SettingsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    }

    private void ChangeTheme_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = notifyProperty;
        int notifySettings = 0;
        if ((bool)DarkTheme_btn.IsChecked)
        {
            notifySettings = 2;
            AppSettings.saveThemeSettings(notifySettings);
            PopupText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            popup_animate.Begin();
        }
        else if ((bool)LightTheme_btn.IsChecked)
        {
            notifySettings = 1;
            AppSettings.saveThemeSettings(notifySettings);
            PopupText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            popup_animate.Begin();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I am already using a `int notifySettings` to change the settings of the app in `LocalSettingsFolder` and every time on app restart it loads the settings in `App.xaml`. Every time I change the settings I call a function in another `class` and it changes the settings and a `animation` is played when I click one of those two `radiobuttons` in `SettingsPage.xaml`. This is the old method.

Now I want to bind these events together so that I don't have to use `int notifySettings` and the `PopupText` animation should play as it does already whenever the `Theme Settings` gets updated. This is how I can also learn about the `INotifyPropertyChanged Event`.

The `int notifySettings` passes a `int` value to change the setting accordingly.
1 = LightTheme and 2 = DarkTheme.

Here is the `Settings Class`:

```
namespace Testing.Pages
{
  class AppSettings
  {
    public static void saveThemeSettings(int value)
    {
        ApplicationDataContainer themeSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        themeSettings.Values["AppThemeSetting"] = value.ToString();
    }

    public static string readThemeSettings()
    {
        ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        string appSettingsString = "error, nothing found";
        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("AppThemeSetting"))
        {
            appSettingsString = localSettings.Values["AppThemeSetting"]?.ToString();
        }
        return appSettingsString;
    }

    public static void removeLocalSettings(string settingValue)
    {
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Remove(settingValue);
    }

  }

}
```

If there is still any ambiguity please let me know and I can try to explain further. I hope someone can help me on this.

**Update:**

I made changes to my project according to the answer by Danny Bogers but the required `Animation` does not start and I think it is because the function is not even being called. I made some more changes and tried to do things on my own but it didn't really work out so I am going to use my own method to do the changes until someone else comes up with a solution.

Comment: You made the comment `// calling OnPropertyChanged whenever the property gets updated`, you need to actually show the code for that, or does your real code just have that comment?

Comment: I actually got the code from Microsoft blog and I edited it a bit and it was written there so I kept it. But I need to know how can I implement these functions together. So I can learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PropertyChanged needs to know **which property has changed**, so you have to pass the name of it.

Make it look like this:

```
public string SettingProperty
{
    get { return _setting; }
    set
    {
        if(_setting != value) // Or String.Equals(_setting, value, ...)
        {
             _setting = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(); // Invoke using no argument.
        }
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The OnPropertyChanged method uses a [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on its parameter that is also optional. This means the compiler will use this argument and replace ith with the actual name of the Caller. So dont pass any value yourself.

It is the equivalent of `PropertyChanged("SettingProperty")`. The Attribute however makes it safe to refractor.

Regarding the rest of your question: I bellieve that the question itself is too brought and consists of atleast more than one propblem. So once you fixed the propertychanged part, rather asked a new question with the specific problem.

Comment: Do I need to update the `SettingProperty` from somewhere else? Or do I need to pass the value for `_setting`?

Comment: @Ahmar SettingProperty. It doesnt notice changes to _setting obviously. If you want to update _setting direchtly, then call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SettingProperty));` afterwards manually.

Comment: Thankyou, `OnPropertyChanged()` was indeed not working first and removing `value` from it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the best at explaining things, I hope you get the gist of it!
I have also not had the time to test it properly, but this should do the job.

You can subscribe to an event via the `+=` syntax. Now, whenever the the event is raised, all subscribers are fired with the given arguments. In this case an instance of `PropertyChangedEventArgs`. This allows your subscribers to behave differently depending on the values from the given `EventArgs` (you can also pass an empty instance of `EventArgs` to your subscribers which means your subscribers won't be doing anything based on the values from the `EventArgs`).

Some minor changes:

- Added an enum for themes. Adds type safety when checking which theme is selected. This is better than checking for a hardcoded string.
- Added an exception when the ThemeSetting cannot be found. You can handle the exception accordingly in a try/catch block. This is, again, better than checking for a hard coded string.
- Added a const string for your appsetting key. This will, just like the previous two points, prevent you from runtime errors due to a typo/give you one central place to manage the value.

  ```
  namespace Testing.Pages
  {
      public enum Themes
      {
          Light = 1,
          Dark = 2
      }
  }

  namespace Testing.Pages
  {
      public class ThemeSettingNotFoundException : Exception
      {
          public ThemeSettingNotFoundException() : base("error, nothing found")
          {
          }
      }

  }

  namespace Testing.Pages
  {
      class BindingClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
      {
          private string _setting;
          public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

          public BindingClass() {

          }

          public BindingClass(string value) {
              _setting = value;
          }

          public string SettingProperty
          {
              get { return _setting; }
              set
              {
                  if(!_setting.Equals(value)){
                      _setting = value;
                      OnPropertyChanged();
                  }
              }
          }

          protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string _setting = "") {
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_setting));
          }
      }
  }


  namespace Testing.Pages
  {

      /// <summary>
      /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
      /// </summary>
      public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
      {
          BindingClass notifyProperty = new BindingClass();

          public SettingsPage() {
              this.InitializeComponent();
              NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;

              //Subscribe to the PropertyChanged event
              notifyProperty.PropertyChanged += OnThemeSettingChanged;
          }

          private void ChangeTheme_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
              DataContext = notifyProperty;
              SaveThemeSettings();
          }

          private void SaveThemeSettings()
          {
              var notifySettings = 0;
              if ((bool)DarkTheme_btn.IsChecked)
                  notifySettings = 2;
              else if ((bool)LightTheme_btn.IsChecked)
                  notifySettings = 1;

              //Only save theme settings when a button was checked
              if (notifySettings != 0)
                  AppSettings.saveThemeSettings((Themes)notifySettings);
          }

          private void OnThemeSettingChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
          {
              PopupText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
              popup_animate.Begin();
          }
      }
  }


  namespace Testing.Pages
  {
      class AppSettings
      {
          private const string ThemeSettingKey = "AppThemeSetting";

          public static void saveThemeSettings(Themes theme) {
              ApplicationDataContainer themeSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
              themeSettings.Values[ThemeSettingKey] = theme.ToString();
          }

          public static Themes readThemeSettings() {
              ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
              if (!localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(ThemeSettingKey))
                  throw new ThemeSettingNotFoundException();
              var appSettingsString = localSettings.Values[ThemeSettingKey];
              return (Themes)Enum.Parse(typeof(Themes), appSettingsString);
          }

          public static void removeLocalSettings(string settingValue) {
              ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Remove(settingValue);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: In your SettingProperty setter, you should add a if (_setting != value) check to prevent errant code from overcalling OnPropertyChanged() since that is kind of expensive.

Comment: I implemented the said changes in your answer but it doesn't work. The animation doesn't run even though the theme settings get changed.

Comment: The implementation is wrong, OnPropertyChangedEventArgs need the name of the property passed and not some arbitrary value. Thats why the implementation of it uses CallerMemberName and an optional string. Just invoke like this  `OnPropertyChanged()`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback CSharpie and SledgeHammer. I've incorporated them into my answer.